# Setting up Firebase. Can't find databaseURL

Tags: firebase

When setting up Firebase I can't find the database URL, the API key is there,
but no database URL. Any ideas?
(Using Thunkable, btw)

Answer (score 1):

This means your Realtime Database hasn't been created yet when you got the configuration data.

To fix this, click on the [Realtime Database](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database) link in the console, create it, and redownload the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Realtime Database first. If you still cannot sea it after that, try refreshing your page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).