# Firebase DatabaseURL not showing in config even after Realtime Database creation

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to run a python firebase_admin setup script to use Firestore. Obviously, this requires a `databaseURL`. However, my project does not appear to have a database URL in the configuration.

What I have tried:

- Inputting my database name as a `https://____.firebaseio.com` url (gives 404 error)
- Many stackoverflow and github posts have suggested creating a Realtime Database first (even for Firestore, for some reason)

(Such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66188976/setting-up-firebase-cant-find-databaseurl) or [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4211))

My python code is nothing special (essentially just the default code)

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db

cred_obj = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate('credentials.json')
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred_obj, {'databaseURL':"https://{my project name}.firebaseio.com"})
```

Which gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: URL has an invalid label.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
firebase_admin.exceptions.UnknownError: Unknown error while making a remote service call: URL has an invalid label.
```

Overall, I simply need advice on how to create / retrieve a databaseURL for Firestore.

Comment: Just to verify, are you trying to read/write data from/to Firestore or from Realtime Database? Because the context of the post looks like you're trying to use Firestore, but based on the code you provided you're trying to use Realtime Database.

Also, it looks like databaseURL is no longer required for authentication based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#initialize

Comment: You're missing a comma after `cred_obj` in your code.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen That's just a transcription error copying it across to stackoverflow (it's not in my original code) but thank you for pointing it out. The issue is that firebase isn't giving me a databaseURL anyway.

Comment: @Alejandro Alejandre That was my confusing too. Many people online were having Firestore databaseURL issues, and others were suggesting that by adding a Realtime Database, it would fix Firestore databaseURL (which doesn't make sense to me either, but supposedly fixed the issue for others, and in the end didn't work for me).